# Using jsoup to post login

Tags: java, jsoup

I have following form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
       Email:
      <input size="20" type="text" name="email" value="" /> Pass:
      <input size="20" type="password" name="password" /> 
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="logt" /> 
      <input type="submit" value="loggy" /> 
     </form>
```

Java code (doesn't work):

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://website/").data("email", "myemail",
            "password", "mypassword").method(Method.POST).execute();
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Do you have any stack trace? What is the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form handler process may require the `action` field. Try adding it

```
Jsoup.connect("http://website/")
        .data("email", "myemail", "password", "mypassword", "action", "logt")
        .method(Method.POST).execute();
```